# Existence of minimum distance from a point to a sequentially compact set?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, compactness

Let K be a non-empty sequentially compact subset of the reals.
Let x be a fixed element in the reals.
Prove that there exists z which is an element of K such that |x - z| = inf {|x-k|}, where the inf is taken over all k in K.

So if I can find a sequence in K which converges to z, then I think I'm done because K is sequentially compact, so z must be an element of K.

Things I might have to use : 
1) Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem ( we have to use the fact K is sequentially compact, so subsequences must come into play..)
2) Completeness of the reals ( inf {|x-k|} exists because 0 is a lower bound. )
3) Triangle inequality

But I don't know how to actually construct a sequence which converges to z.. I'd like some hints which involve sequences (we haven't started functions yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $m:=\inf\{|x-k|: k\in K\}$ with $m+\dfrac{1}{n}>|x-k_{n}|\geq m$ for each $n=1,2,...$

Comment: To be precise, $m+1/n$ is not the greatest lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c=\inf\{|x-k|:\ k\in k\} $. There are elements $k_n $ in $K $ such that $|x-k_n|\to c$. There exists $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, $$c\leq|x-k_n|<c+1. $$ Then $$|k_n|\leq|x-k_n|+|x|\leq c+1+|x|. $$ Thus the sequence  $\{k_n\}$ is bounded. This allows you to choose a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.. How do you get the first inequality? And how do we know that there exists a sequence in K such that |x-kn| ->c?

Comment: Exactly the things you mentioned you had to use: the triangle inequality and the definition of infimum.